# unable to pip install in visual studio code terminal

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal, module, pip

I tried to download the requests module but every time I try in the vscode terminal. It asks me to choose an app to open the file and when I choose it opens pip file (which is located in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\pip`) I don't know what is wrong. please help
the second image is the code that I tried to execute and the first image is what happens after I executed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share command you are typing and output screenshot

Comment: Chandan the second image is the code that I tried to execute and the first image is what happens after I executed.

Comment: did you added python bin folder in `PATH`.

Comment: I haven't I will try

Comment: you can check by running `where pip` in powershell

Comment: I just did but it still doesn't work

Comment: when you run `where pip` what is shown in powershell .

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\pip
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe

Comment: I can use pip normally in the cmd but not in the powershell in visual studio

Comment: `python` PATH is shown in between that's why maybe its not working because it is finding pip in `System32` folder.

Comment: so I have to delete that pip in system32

Comment: how did you installed `python` in your system from anaconda or python installer from main site.

Comment: I installed it at python.org